# Classes Exceptions and Operators

Tags: c++, class, exception, namespaces, operators

I am having some trouble getting a lot of the operators to work

The instruction for the assignment is as follows

> The purpose of this assignment is to work with exceptions.  As you may
>   recall, I have provided you with a sample class named FlashDrive which
>   has been diagrammed below.  You can acquire the source to the
>   FlashDrive class here ( .NET or .NET 2010)  I'd like you to enhance
>   this class so that invoking its methods or operators potentially throw
>   exceptions, rather than just printing error messages to cout. 
>   Currently, our favorite exception class is std::logic_error.  You can
>   create a logic_error by passing a string value to its constructor. 
>   Officially, you should also say #include  to begin working
>   with logic_error, but Visual Studio (being a badly behaved child...)
>   let's you get away without it.  Once you get it all working correctly,
>   the driver code should run as described in class.
>
> Although the sample driver code might not code for all these
>   circumstances, I would like you to throw exceptions when:
>
> more stuff has been put onto the drive than it can safely hold (due to
>   writeData)
>
> a negative number is potentially used as a my_StorageUsed value (due
>   to operator – or bad values being sent to the constructor call)
>
> a negative number is potentially used as a my_StorageCapacity value
>   (due to operator – or bad values being sent to the constructor call)
>   So carefully wind your way thru all the operators and methods of the
>   class ensuring that logic_error gets thrown in each of these
>   circumstances.
>
> I'd also like you to get operator << and operator >> working for the
>   class FlashDrive.  And finally, I'd like you to place FlashDrive into
>   the namespace cs52.

Below is my code and build output

**FlashDrive.h**

```
#ifndef FLASHDRIVE_H
#define FLASHDRIVE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace cs52 {

class FlashDrive {
    friend FlashDrive operator+ (FlashDrive used1 , FlashDrive used2);
    friend FlashDrive operator- (FlashDrive used3, FlashDrive used4 );

public:

    FlashDrive& FlashDrive::operator=(int);
    FlashDrive::FlashDrive(int);
    FlashDrive& operator = (const FlashDrive& usedtotal){
        my_StorageUsed= usedtotal.my_StorageUsed;
        return *this;
    }
    FlashDrive( );
    FlashDrive( int capacity, int used, bool pluggedIn );

    void plugIn( );
    void pullOut( );
    void writeData( int amount );
    void eraseData( int amount );
    void formatDrive( );

    int  getCapacity( );
    void setCapacity( int amount );
    int  getUsed( );
    void setUsed( int amount );
    bool isPluggedIn( );

private:
    int my_StorageCapacity;   // in kilobytes
    int my_StorageUsed;       // in kilobytes
    bool my_IsPluggedIn;      // am I attached to a computer?
}extern drive1,drive2;

inline FlashDrive operator+ (FlashDrive used1, FlashDrive used2 ) {

    FlashDrive plus;

    plus.my_StorageUsed = (used1.getUsed()+ used2.getUsed());
    return plus;
}
inline bool operator< (FlashDrive &lhs,FlashDrive &rhs ) {
   return ( lhs.getUsed() < rhs.getUsed() );
}
inline bool operator> (FlashDrive &lhs,FlashDrive &rhs ) {
   return ( operator <( rhs, lhs ) );
}
inline FlashDrive operator - (FlashDrive used3, FlashDrive used4 ){
    FlashDrive minus;
    minus.my_StorageUsed = (used3.getUsed()- used4.getUsed());
    return minus;
};

}
#endif
```

**FlashDrive.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "FlashDrive.h"

namespace cs52 {

FlashDrive::FlashDrive( ) {
  my_StorageCapacity = 0;
  my_StorageUsed = 0;
  my_IsPluggedIn = false;
}
FlashDrive::FlashDrive( int capacity, int used, bool pluggedIn ) { 
  my_StorageCapacity = capacity;
  my_StorageUsed = used;
  my_IsPluggedIn = pluggedIn;
}
void FlashDrive::plugIn( ) {
  my_IsPluggedIn = true;
}
void FlashDrive::pullOut( ) {
  my_IsPluggedIn = false;
}
void FlashDrive::writeData( int amount ) {
  my_StorageUsed += amount;
}
void FlashDrive::eraseData( int amount ) {
  my_StorageUsed -= amount;
}
void FlashDrive::formatDrive( ) {
  my_StorageUsed = 0;
}

int  FlashDrive::getCapacity( ) {
  return( my_StorageCapacity );
}
void FlashDrive::setCapacity( int amount ) {
  my_StorageCapacity = amount;
}
int  FlashDrive::getUsed( ) {
  return( my_StorageUsed );
}
void FlashDrive::setUsed( int amount ) {
  my_StorageUsed = amount;
}
bool FlashDrive::isPluggedIn( ) {
  return( my_IsPluggedIn );
}
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "FlashDrive.h"
void main( )
{
using namespace cs52;
cs52::FlashDrive empty;
cs52::FlashDrive drive1( 10, 0, false );
cs52::FlashDrive drive2( 20, 0, false );

drive1.plugIn( );
drive1.formatDrive( );
drive1.writeData( 5 );
drive1.pullOut( );

drive2.plugIn( );
drive2.formatDrive( );
drive2.writeData( 1 );
drive2.pullOut( );

// read in a FlashDrive... 
// the class designer for FlashDrive (that's you!)
// gets to decide which fields matter and should be read in
cs52::FlashDrive sample;
cin >> sample;

// print out a FlashDrive...
// the class designer for FlashDrive (that's you!)
// gets to decide which fields matter and should be printed
cout << sample << endl;

cs52::FlashDrive combined = drive1 + drive2;
cout << "this drive's filled to " << combined.getUsed( ) << endl;

cs52::FlashDrive other = combined – drive1;
cout << "the other cup's filled to " << other.getUsed( ) << endl;

if (combined > other) {
  cout << "looks like combined is bigger..." << endl;
}
else {
  cout << "looks like other is bigger..." << endl;
}

if (drive2 > other) {
  cout << "looks like drive2 is bigger..." << endl;
}
else {
  cout << "looks like other is bigger..." << endl;
}

if (drive2 < drive1) {
  cout << "looks like drive2 is smaller..." << endl;
}
else {
  cout << "looks like drive1 is smaller..." << endl;
}

// let's throw some exceptions...

try {
  empty = empty - combined;
  cout << "something not right here..." << endl;
} catch( std::logic_error ) {
// an exception should get thrown... 
// so the lines of code here should
// be run, not the cout statement...
}

try {
  drive2.writeData( 10000 );
  cout << "something not right here..." << endl;
} catch( std::logic_error ) {
// an exception should get thrown... 
// so the lines of code here should
// be run, not the cout statement...
}

try {
  cs52::FlashDrive f( -1, -1, false );
  cout << "something not right here..." << endl;
} catch( std::logic_error ) {
// an exception should get thrown... 
// so the lines of code here should
// be run, not the cout statement...
}
}
```

And here a very strange error message i'm getting

> ------ Build started: Project: FlashDriver, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------ Build started 7/29/2013 4:48:43 AM. InitializeBuildStatus:   Touching "Debug\FlashDriver.unsuccessfulbuild". ClCompile:   Main.cpp
>   c:\documents and settings\administrator\my documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\flashdriver\flashdriver\main.cpp(28): error C2678:
>   binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of
>   type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>             c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1053): could be 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
>
> > > >(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1060): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       >(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1067): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       >(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,unsigned char *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1074): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       >(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,unsigned char &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1097): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       >(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1104): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       >(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1111): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       >(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1118): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       >(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1128): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       ,cs52::FlashDrive>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &&,_Ty &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits,
> > >                     _Ty=cs52::FlashDrive
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(179): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator
> > >       (std::basic_istream<_Elem,*Traits> &(*_cdecl *)(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(185): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator
> > >       (std::basic_ios<_Elem,*Traits> &(*_cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(192): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::ios_base
> > >       &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(199): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::_Bool &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(218): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(short &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(253): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned short &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(272): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(int &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(298): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned int &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(316): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(334): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned long &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(354): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,*Traits>::operator >>(*_int64 &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(373): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned __int64 &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(392): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(float &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(411): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(double &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(429): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long double &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(447): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(void *&)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(466): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator
> > >       (std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 while trying to match the argument list '(std::istream, cs52::FlashDrive)' c:\documents and settings\administrator\my
> > >       documents\visual studio
> > >       2010\projects\flashdriver\flashdriver\main.cpp(33): error C2679:
> > >       binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of
> > >       type 'cs52::FlashDrive' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &,const char *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &,char)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const
> > >       char *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const
> > >       signed char *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed
> > >       char)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const
> > >       unsigned char *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &,unsigned char)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(968): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<,cs52::FlashDrive>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &&,_Ty)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits,
> > >                     _Ty=cs52::FlashDrive
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator
> > >       <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &,const std::error_code &)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(186): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator
> > >       <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,*Traits> &(*_cdecl
> > >       *)(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(192): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator
> > >       <<(std::basic_ios<_Elem,*Traits> &(*_cdecl
> > >       *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(199): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::ios_base
> > >       &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(206): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(226): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(short)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(260): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned short)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(280): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(int)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(305): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned int)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(325): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(345): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned long)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(366): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,*Traits>::operator <<(*_int64)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(386): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned __int64)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(407): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(float)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(427): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(double)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(447): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long double)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(467): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(const void *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(487): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
> > >       &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator
> > >       <<(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
> > >                 with
> > >                 [
> > >                     _Elem=char,
> > >                     _Traits=std::char_traits
> > >                 ]
> > >                 while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, cs52::FlashDrive)' c:\documents and settings\administrator\my
> > >       documents\visual studio
> > >       2010\projects\flashdriver\flashdriver\main.cpp(38): error C2146:
> > >       syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '–' c:\documents and
> > >       settings\administrator\my documents\visual studio
> > >       2010\projects\flashdriver\flashdriver\main.cpp(38): error C2065: '–' :
> > >       undeclared identifier c:\documents and settings\administrator\my
> > >       documents\visual studio
> > >       2010\projects\flashdriver\flashdriver\main.cpp(38): error C2146:
> > >       syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'drive1'   FlashDrive.cpp
> > >       Generating Code...
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.82
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: what have you tried? How is the error message strange, if you have no operator>> specified anywhere for your `FlashDrive` class?

Comment: The first error message tells you that you have not defined an `operator>>`, which is true. Work you way step by step through the error messages and ask more specific questions, if possible with an SSCE (http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `operator>>` for `class FlashDrive`

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, FlashDrive& fd)
{
  is >> my_StorageCapacity >> my_StorageUsed >> my_IsPluggedIn;
  return is;
}
```

Similar you could define `operator<<`

```
std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream& os, const FlashDrive& fd)
{
  os << fd.getCapacity() << fd.getUsed() << fd.isPluggedIn();
  return os;
}
```